# How to set onitemSelectedListener for the spinner inside for loop

Tags: android

I have created view dynamically through for loop. It also contains multiple spinners. I have used onItemSelectedListener for the spinner to select value. Whenever user click spinner I have used some logic to save the spinner value in the database, but onItemSelectedListener is called even before clicking the spinner inside the for loop.

How could spinner methods are only called when clicked but not for every for loop iteration ?

```
//set the questions for the user dynamically with the for loop
    for (int ss = 0; ss < totalNoOfQuestions.size(); ss++) {
        pos = ss;
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("SELECT");
        TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        textView.setTypeface(typeface1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        String questText = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getParagraphQuestion();
        final String questionNum = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getQuestionNo();
        String question = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getQuestions();
        textView.setText(questText + " " + questionNum + "   " + question);

        spinner[ss] = new Spinner(activity);
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfQuestions.get(0).getOptions().size(); i++) {
            String option = totalNoOfQuestions.get(0).getOptions().get(i).getQuestionOptionNo();
            list.add(option);
        }
        spinner[ss].setId(ss);
        spinner[ss].setMinimumWidth(100);

        //spinner.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_gradient));
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        spinner[ss].getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        //spinner.setBackground(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_gradient));
        spinner[ss].setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //retrieve value from the database if user already selected
        List<QuestionsNAnswers> inventories = getAll();
        for(int k = 0 ; k<inventories.size() ;k++){
            QuestionsNAnswers questionsNAnswers = inventories.get(k);
            String quesNo = questionsNAnswers.questionNo;
            spinner[ss].setSelection(Integer.parseInt(quesNo));
        }

        final int finalSs = ss;
        spinner[ss].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // Toast.makeText(activity, "You Selected " + selection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int spinnerId = spinner[finalSs].getId();
                questionNo = totalNoOfQuestions.get(spinnerId).getQuestionNo();
                optionNo = spinner[finalSs].getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                //save the options in the database
                QuestionsNAnswers questionsNAnswers = new QuestionsNAnswers();
                questionsNAnswers.questionNo = questionNo;
                questionsNAnswers.optionSelected = optionNo;
                //save the records in the database
                questionsNAnswers.save();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        linearLayoutForQuestions.addView(textView);
        linearLayoutForQuestions.addView(spinner[ss]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution but should work.
Do another listener ontouchlistener which change some value and performClick on spinner.
Then inside spinner, add value to db only if value is true and reset value.